# Alert views with if statements

Tags: ios, udp, push-notification, alert

I am creating an alarm app that sends udp data when the alarm goes off. At the moment the udp data is sending as soon as the alarm is set, not when the alarm goes off. I was thinking i could do this using an if statement? I think this is the right bit of the code. Please help!!

```
-(void)scheduleloalNotificationWithDate:(NSDate *)fireDate {
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

notification.fireDate = fireDate;
notification.alertBody = @"Time For Coffee!";

SwitchOn= [sendOn dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *newIP = [setting IP];
NSLog(@"IP = %@", newIP);
if(!newIP){
    [socket sendData: SwitchOn toHost: @"192.168.0.2" port: 5900 withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
    // NSLog(@"cancel");
}
  else{
 [socket sendData:SwitchOn toHost: newIP port: 5900 withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
 }

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification: notification];

[notification release];
}
```

Comment: So you are wanting to use an Action the user does on an AlertView to decide what to do next?

Answer (score 0):

The application might be terminated after the notification is scheduled but before fired. As a  user i could dismiss the notification not opening the app, which means the data will not always be sent. There also will appear a race condition for multiple updates if the user is using the same app with several devices.

If you still want to update the data when the application is fired instead of when it is scheduled, the `UILocalNotification` [overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will help you to understand all the situations you'll have to handle.

PS you've missed `c` at `scheduleloalNotificationWithDate`